# Binary conversion program

Tags: javascript, math, binary

I am trying to make a program that converts a decimal number into a binary number of up to 10 digits, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my current code. I'm quite new to programming so it's possible I've not picked up on something tiny. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

HTML body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Binary converter</title>
    <script src="binaryConverter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <div>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Insert a decimal number to be converted to binary: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="decimal" placeholder="e.g. 54"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" onClick="calc()">Convert</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Your result: </td>
                    <td id="resultCell"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript body:

````
function calc() {

    var result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,];
    var decimal = document.getElementById("decimal").value;

    result[9] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[9];

    result[8] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[8];

    result[7] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[7];

    result[6] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[6];

    result[5] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[5];

    result[4] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[4];

    result[3] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[3];

    result[2] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[2];

    result[1] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[1];

    result[0] == decimal % 2;
    decimal == result[0];

    document.getElementById("resultCell").innerHTML = 
    result[9].toString() +
    result[8].toString() +
    result[7].toString() +
    result[6].toString() +
    result[5].toString() +
    result[4].toString() +
    result[3].toString() +
    result[2].toString() +
    result[1].toString() +
    result[0].toString();
}
    ```
````

Comment: You store the same number in every element of your `result` array.

Comment: You don't actually. You only compare those numbers. (`==` compares, `=` assigns)

Comment: what I was trying to do was have the value of "decimal" be overwritten every time arithmetic is performed on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to read each binary digit individually. You can achieve this using bitwise operations:

- `>>` shifts a number to the right: `0b1000 >> 2 === 0b0010`
- `&` performs a bitwise and: `(0b1001 & 0b1110) === 0b1000`

Using these operators you can implement your algorithm.

The `%` operator divides a number by another one and returns the remainder: `15 % 2 === 1`, `1 % 2 === 1`

Answer (score 1):

`==` operator is for comparison not assignment, you should use `=` instead

You may also shorten it with loop:

```js
function calc() {

    var result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,];
    var decimal = document.getElementById("decimal").value;

    for(let i=result.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        result[i] = decimal % 2;
        decimal = Math.floor(decimal / 2);
    }
    document.getElementById("resultCell").innerHTML = result.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to use a built in Javascript function to convert decimal to binary, simply use `toString(2)`.  See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp .

```js
console.log( (15).toString(2) )
console.log( (65536).toString(2) )
```

It even works with BigInt (although currently BigInt is not natively implemented in Microsoft browsers).

```js
console.log( (123456789012345678901234567890n).toString(2) )
```